# Getting a higher resolution of nyquist plot

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to get a higher resolution of a nyquist plot?

The bode plot for example includes the posibility to increase the frequency resolution.

I use that code:

```
T=64.38 %ms

G_1=tf([-T 1],[T^2 2*T 1]);
zpk(G_1)
G_2=tf([1],[T 1]);
zpk(G_2)

G=G_1*G_1*G_1*G_2;

zpk(G)

nyquist(G)
```

Comment: what do you mean by higher resolution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This info is found in the documentation: you can specify a frequency range for nyquist:

```
w = -10:0.001:0;
nyquist(G,exp(w))
```

Comment: I can't find that passage. (I'm using Matlab R2009b) But It work's.